# Trying to connect 2.1 speakers to a TV

Tags: television, speakers

A friend of mine has a Samsung TV (Model UE40J5250) to which he would like to connect an analogue 2.1 speaker system for better sound. Unfortunately, this low-end TV has a very limited number of interfaces.

The only two interfaces which seem adequate to me are an optical audio output port (a.k.a. TOSLINK) and RCA. As offers for TOSLINK to 3.5mm jack adapters I found so far are extremely expensive, I bought a cable that is RCA on the one side (which I plugged into the TV) and 3.5mm jack on the other side (which I plugged into the subwoofer).

This didn't work. May the RCA port on the TV a dedicated input port? The TV's manual is not very detailed.

Here's a picture of the connections on the back of the TV:

[image]

Comment: #TIL: [Cinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) is a non-US term for an RCA (or phono plug) connector.

Comment: Please define "didn't work". If all your audio output is going to the subwoofer, you're only going to get the deepest bass sounds out of the sub, and all the "normal" bass, mid-range and high-end will be filtered out by the sub's electronics, leaving basically no audio at all. Also, double check that these are _output_ ports, not _input_ ports. If it's a set of white / red / _yellow_ then it's most likely _input_ as the yellow is a composite video input and the red/white are the audio input to go with it.

Comment: The subwoofer receives the signals for the whole 2.1 speaker system.

Comment: I'd still double check to ensure that these are designed for output, not input.

Comment: As I posted originally, the TV's manual does not clarify whether it's input, output or both.

Comment: Is it a red/white pair or red/white/yellow triplet?

Comment: It's like on this pic: https://itsosticky.com/95u7ln

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because operation of appliances and product recommendations are both off-topic here.

Comment: Is there a sub-site on StackExchange where my issue would be on-topic?

Comment: The RCA ports on the TV are labeled at the top as IN so they are inputs not out. (*see Freeman's answer*) "*The only two interfaces which seem adequate*"  Does that mean there are others that you have not shown us? Also you have not told us what the available inputs into the 2.1 system are.  I suggest you go to the AVS forum. https://www.avsforum.com/forums/speakers.89/  Toslink to RCA converter, RCA to 3.5 jack adapter should get you there. Is that enough for the sub?, not enough info.

Comment: Toslink to an AVR (*Audio Video Receiver*) unit will give you more connection options. Even an old cheap used one.  But again, i don't know what 2.1 system you have.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the picture linked in your comment is actually of the TV in question I've highlighted the issue here:

[image]

That says:

> COMPONENT / AV ***IN***

There is no way in the world you're going to get any sound out of any of those jacks. My apologies, in the comments, I was asking about a red/white/yellow set, which would be *Composite* IN, this is a *Component* IN where the video come in on the Red/Blue/Green set, and the audio comes in on the Red/White set.

Next to it, at the bottom, it reads:

> DIGITAL AUDIO ***OUT*** / OPTICAL

If you want Audio *output* that's your go to. Even if the TOSLINK connector is more expensive, it's probably cheaper than buying a new TV with other audio out options.

Comment: I mostly agree, but the analog audio connections could be in/out, just as the top RCA jack is both composite (yellow) video and component (RGB green channel). Functions can vary depending on menu selection.

Comment: @isherwood I'd agree with you _except_ that they are labeled "IN", while the TOSLINK connection to the left is labeled "OUT". Also, the OP doesn't seem to be getting any output...

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting "The subwoofer receives the signals for the whole 2.1 speaker system".

Comment: @isherwood yes, the "subwoofer receives the signal", separates the low-band signal for itself and passes the rest on for the other speakers to reproduce. That is assuming that it's actually attached to an _output_ source. The jacks in the picture are _input_ jacks allowing the TV to display picture/sound provided _to_ it from a DVD/BluRay/other. It appears, based on the pic provided, that this TV has only one output - the "Digital Audio Out" also known as TOSLINK. [con't...]

Comment: Connecting the TV to the sub via these RCA jacks is like running 14/2 between two ceiling fixtures and wondering why they won't light up. It's because there's no power (signal) going into the fixtures. The TV and sub are both expecting signal _input_ on the connectors that the OP seems to be using, and nobody is supplying any signal _output_.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, you must use an *audio output* to connect to the speaker system. The reason the adapters you've found (TOSLINK -> 3.5mm "headphone") are expensive is because TOSLINK is digital and optical (uses fiber optic lasers to communicate with a digital receiver) and 3.5mm (known as "headphone jacks") is an analog electrical contact type interface. Since you'd need an actual converter and not just a cable, you can expect to pay more.

Some older TVs will have a headphone (3.5mm) output port, possibly on the side near channel/menu buttons and not on the back where the inputs/outputs are located. Even though these are meant for headphone/hearing aid use for accessibility, the audio they output can be run through a speaker system, but it will not be as high-quality as an optical digital output.

Comment: Excellent point! Of course, once converted from the digital TOSLINK output to an analog signal at the 3.5mm output jack, significant audio quality will probably be gone anyway...